# Win 10 fails to recognize the .bat & .cmd extensions for jmeter in %PATHEXT%

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, jmeter

Why my Win 10 is not recognizing jmeter `.bat` & `.cmd` commands -- `jmeterw.cmd` and `jmeter.bat` run just fine. But without the extension (`jmeterw` and `jmeter`) they will fail. I've never seen such problem before:

```
C:\>set PATH=D:\Programs\apache-jmeter-5.4\bin;%PATH%

C:\>where jmeter
D:\Programs\apache-jmeter-5.4\bin\jmeter.bat

C:\>jmeter
'jmeter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\>where jmeter-no-no
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).

C:\>where jmeterw
D:\Programs\apache-jmeter-5.4\bin\jmeterw.cmd

C:\>jmeterw
'jmeterw' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\>D:\Programs\apache-jmeter-5.4\bin\jmeterw.cmd
'jmeter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\>jmeterw.cmd
'jmeter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\>jmeter.bat
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
...

C:\>set pathext
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC

C:\>echo %pathext%
.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC


C:\>ver
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.630]
```

Everything works just fine in my another old machine, and I can't tell the differences between the two except the Windows version.

**UPDATE:**

@Compo, my `%PATHEXT%` variable is unlike the cause as this is a brand new machine provided by our IT department, neither them nor I would fiddle that. On the same machine other `.bat`/`.cmd` command works just fine. Only those jmeter ones are problematic.

> what it looks like when transferred by you into your question area and formatted, does not prove to me that your semicolons and periods are the correct characters, they just look like them.

They are good. To ensure you, I've verified with my `hexdump -C` from my WSL:

```
00000000  2e 43 4f 4d 3b 2e 45 58  45 3b 2e 42 41 54 3b 2e  |.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.|
00000010  43 4d 44 3b 2e 56 42 53  3b 2e 56 42 45 3b 2e 4a  |CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.J|
00000020  53 3b 2e 4a 53 45 3b 2e  57 53 46 3b 2e 57 53 48  |S;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH|
00000030  3b 2e 4d 53 43                                    |;.MSC|

$ echo '.;' | hexdump -C
00000000  2e 3b 0a                                          |.;.|
00000003
```

Anyway, I've done the registry setting with the command you gave me,

[image]

and open a new cmd.exe instance for testing after having done that. But the problem remain exactly the same.

**PS**

> On the same machine other `.bat`/`.cmd` command works just fine.

Just to illustrate that:

```
where kotlin
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).

set PATH=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc\bin;%PATH%

C:\>where kotlin
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc\bin\kotlin
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc\bin\kotlin.bat

C:\>where kotlinc
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc\bin\kotlinc
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc\bin\kotlinc.bat

C:\>kotlinc
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xms512M -Xmx1g
Apr 09, 2021 9:50:20 AM org.jline.utils.Log logr
. . .
```

**Final UPDATE:**

Found where the problem is:

```
copy D:\Programs\jmeter\bin\jmeter.bat C:\Temp

set PATH=C:\Temp;%PATH%

C:\>where jmeter
C:\Temp\jmeter.bat
D:\Programs\jmeter\bin\jmeter.bat

C:\>jmeter
The JMETER_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program

C:\>D:\Programs\jmeter\bin\jmeter
'D:\Programs\jmeter\bin\jmeter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\>C:\Temp\jmeter
The JMETER_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
```

BINGO! It runs from `C:` but not from `D:`. What's problem running from `D:`? The situation is, this is a brand new machine provided by our IT department which has only a single `C:` drive. I shrunk it and added `D:` drive myself. Never thought *that* would cause me trouble. How to solve it?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like `D:\Programs\apache-jmeter-5.4\bin` isn't part of your `%PATH%` variable.

Comment: No @SomethingDark, check my updated commands, jmeterw.cmd and jmeter.bat run just fine. Just without the extension they fail. Should not happen. I've never seen such problem before.

Comment: Check `set pathext` (or `echo %pathext%`)  -- it should include ;-separated entries for `.bat` and `.cmd` (and more). Check to see what if anything is set for PATHEXT in the registry under HKCU\Environment and HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment

Comment: Search this site for `not recognized as an internal or external command`, and you'll see that this question has been asked (and answered) many times before. **Always** do a basic search for the error message before posting a new question here.

Comment: That works well too @dave_thompson_085, see my updated question. Ken, thanks for the down-vote without any answer.

Comment: I note that both `jmeterw.cmd` and `jmeter.bat` both work, _(the former just fails because it uses `call jmeter %*` i.e. without the extension)_. This suggests that an issue lies with your `%PATHEXT%` variable. Clearly however, `where` works adding the extension `.EXE` from `%PATHEXT%`, so to be sure that the rest of the strings beyond `.EXE;` are using genuine periods, I'd advise that you rewrite its content.

Comment: You could do that from an elevated Command Prompt if you prefer, e.g. `"C:\Windows\System32\reg.exe" Add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /V "PATHEXT" /T "REG_SZ" /D ".COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC" /F` Please open a new `cmd.exe` instance for testing after having done that. For completeness, could you also please post the output from entering just the string `path`.

Comment: @xpt, what it looks like when transferred by you into your question area and formatted, does not prove to me that your semicolons and periods are the correct characters, they just look like them. There is no reason not to overwrite the entry with definitely correct characters to eliminate that possibility. Also, is there a reason why you have not provided the output from `path`, as I asked?

Comment: Thanks @Compo, I'd hesitate to do any registry hacking. Would setting %PATHEXT% variable myself in a new cmd does the same trick?

Comment: @Compo, I've done the registry setting with the command you gave me. See my update above. thanks.

Comment: @xpt, did you by any chance create the jmeter directory in WSL? I ask, because I remembered a while back some issues with directories created that way and case sensitive extensions in `%PATHEXT%`, which as you can see are all upper case. Take a look at the discussion [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3487.).

Comment: if it only happens with those two files, I'd guess it's about those files. Check the fillenames  with your `hexdump` (`dir /b "D:\Programs\jmeter\bin\jmeter.bat"|hexdump -C`) to check if there isn't an additional invisible character at the end (I can't imagine where that would come from but I can't explain it otherwise either)

Comment: Ahhhh!!!! BINGO, Indeed I created the jmeter directory in WSL! I really really should have mentioned that, I couldn't imagine it would matter in any way, but apparently it does. Confirmed, delete it and redo unzip from within Windows get everything back to normal again! Thanks a lot @Compo, my hats off to you, for your knowledge and your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based upon the information you've provided, I recall seeing a discussion about an issue with `%PATHEXT%` related to case sensitivity in directories created using WSL.

Here is a link [Issue #3487](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3487) to that discussion, which also references [Issue #3356](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3356).

It appears WSL can create directories with a property which causes those directories to be case-sensitive. Obviously this means that your `.bat` and `.cmd` extensions, do not then match the `.BAT` and `.CMD` extensions listed under `%PATHEXT%`.

There is some additional official information about this per-directory case sensitivity in a Microsoft blog post, [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/02/28/per-directory-case-sensitivity-and-wsl/). It includes suggested fixes using `fsutil.exe`, or `reg.exe`.

For a quick workaround you could try simply changing the extensions of your two files, from `.bat` to `.BAT` and `.cmd` to `.CMD` respectively. Alternatively you could change your `%PATHEXT%` value string from `.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC` to `.COM;.com;.EXE;.exe;.BAT;.bat;.CMD;.cmd;.VBS;.vbs;.VBE;.vbe;.JS;.js;.JSE;.jse;.WSF;.wsf;.WSH;.wsh;.MSC;.msc`.

An alternative thought, *(untested)* may be to `rename` your directory, then use `robocopy.exe` to copy it to a new directory with the original name.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) environment variable, my expectation is that if you do something like:

```
set PATH="D:\Programs\apache-jmeter-5.4\bin;%PATH%"
```

you will be able to run JMeter as `jmeter` from the same terminal window.

To make the change permanent use [setx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/setx) command:

```
setx /M PATH "D:\Programs\apache-jmeter-5.4\bin;%PATH%"
```

If it doesn't help inspect [assoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/assoc) command output on both machines

More information: [Get Started With JMeter: Installation & Tests](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-get-started-jmeter-installation-test-plans)

Comment: Yeah, Dmitri, that's the standard way of doing things, however as I put it, my current situation _"should not happen. I've never seen such problem before."_